# Reactjs Render Error Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My QuestionList.jsx File Code Is

```
import React from 'react'
import Questions from './Questions'

const QuestionList = ({questionList}) => {
  return (
    <>
      {questionList.map((question) => (
        <Questions question={question} key={question.id}/>
      ))}
    </>
  )
}

export default QuestionList
```

The error I am getting while rendering things are visible but getting this error in console and the link is not getting it.

```
react-jsx-dev-runtime.development.js:87 Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

Check the render method of `QuestionList`. See https://reactjs.org/link/warning-keys for more information.
    at Questions (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:872:5)
    at QuestionList (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:794:5)
    at div
    at div
    at HomeMainbar (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:596:81)
    at div
    at div
    at Questions
    at Routes (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:42703:5)
    at AllRoutes
    at Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:42636:15)
    at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:41445:5)
    at div
    at App
```

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

const Questions = ({question}) => {
  return (
    <div className='display-question-container'>
        
        <div className='display-votes-ans'>
            <p>{question.upVotes}</p>
        <p>Up Votes</p>
        </div>
        <div className='display-votes-ans'>
            <p>{question.downVotes}</p>
            <p>Down Votes</p>
        </div>
        <div className='display-votes-ans'>
            <p>{question.noOfAnswer}</p>
            <p>Answers </p>
        </div>
        <div className="display-question-details">
            <Link to={'/Questions/${question.id}'} className='question-title-link'>{question.questionTitle}</Link>
            <div className='display-tags-time'>
                <div className='display-tags'>
                    {
                        question.questionTags.map((tag) =>(
                            <p key={tag}>{tag}</p>
                        ))
                    }
                </div>
                <p className='display-time'>
                    asked{question.askedOn} { question.userPosted }
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Questions
```

This Is My Question.jsx File

Questions array is:

```
var questionsList = [{
    _id: '1',
    upVotes: 3,
    downVotes: 2,
    noOfAnswers: 2,
    questionTitle:"What Is Function Hmm?",
    questionBody:"It Meant To Be",
    questionTags:["javascript", "r", "python"],
    userPosted: "mano",
    userId: 1,
    askedOn:"jan 1",
    answer: [{
      answerBody: "Answer",
      userAnswered: "kumar",
      answerOn: "jan 2",
      userId: 2,
    }]
  },{
    _id: '2',
    upVotes: 3,
    downVotes:2,
    noOfAnswers: 0,
    questionTitle:"What Is Function In JS?",
    questionBody:"It Meant To Be",
    questionTags:["javascript", "python"],
    userPosted: "lano",
    userId: 1,
    askedOn:"jan 1",
    answer: [{
      answerBody: "Answer",
      userAnswered: "kumar",
      answerOn: " jan 2",
      userId: 2,
    }] 
  },{
    _id: '3',
    upVotes: 1,
    downVotes:0,
    noOfAnswers: 1,
    questionTitle:"How To Use A Function?",
    questionBody:"By Adding Const",
    questionTags:["javascript", "r", "python", "Css"],
    userPosted: "mano",
    userId: 1,
    askedOn:"jan 2",
    answer: [{
      answerBody: "Answer",
      userAnswered: "kumar",
      answerOn: " jan 2",
      userId:2,
    }]

  }]
```

Comment: It's likely that the questions being passed to `QuestionList` have duplicate IDs. Please show us this.

Comment: No Questions Passed Ids Are Not duplicate They All Are Different

Comment: Not according to the error.

Comment: As mentioned, you are getting this error because some of your IDs are duplicated. Using the index as key is just bad practice and hide the real issue which is that your questions don't have unique ids (or you might sometimes have multiple times the same question in your list)

Comment: You've a typo. Based on the data you posted in your duplicate question the data hasn't any `id` property, so all the React keys are the same value, `undefined`. The data *does* appear to have a `_id` property though, so use `key={question._id}` instead. Voting to close as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo". Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

{question.questionTitle}

```
write this code below :

     <Link to={pathname: "/Questions"}>{question.questionTitle}</Link>

or you can write like this also :

This is the actual answer for your code :
    <Link to={`/Questions/${question.id}`} className='question-title-link'>{question.questionTitle}</Link>
```

Comment: The Error Is Solved But Links Are Not Getting Change

Comment: idk what links you talk about men... Likely an other issue.

Comment: could you please give Questions component code

Comment: @yashlohade consider not capitalising the first letter of every word? It makes it harder to read.

Comment: I Have Updated The Question Please View That

Comment: just make sure when you are writing string + your javascript variable then you should have to use backtick instead of Apostrophe , that will lead to a unusual behaviour

Answer (score 1):

As seen in your other post [Reactjs Warning: child in a list should have a unique key" prop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73790822/reactjs-warning-child-in-a-list-should-have-a-unique-key-prop) your questionList does not contain `id` as a property of a question. Instead you should use the `_id` property.

```
questionList.map((question) => (
    <Questions question={question} key={question._id}/>
))
```

Answer (score -2):

maybe your data has same id's. check your data or where you mapping your data add second parameter: index.

and replace value of key with index.

```js
questionList.map((question, index) => (
                <Questions question={question} key={index}/>
           ))
```

Comment: Using the key as index is the same as not putting any key from a react point of view. It will only hide the potential reconciliation issues.

Comment: thanks for this information but since i cannot examine the data, I have no other solution.