# Reactjs Warning: child in a list should have a unique key" prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, key, react-router-dom

i Am Getting This Error Even After Every Id Have Unique Key Prop

```
var questionsList = [{
    _id: '1',
    upVotes: 3,
    downVotes: 2,
    noOfAnswers: 2,
    questionTitle:"What Is Function Hmm?",
    questionBody:"It Meant To Be",
    questionTags:["javascript", "r", "python"],
    userPosted: "mano",
    userId: 1,
    askedOn:"jan 1",
    answer: [{
      answerBody: "Answer",
      userAnswered: "kumar",
      answerOn: "jan 2",
      userId: 2,
    }]
  },{
    _id: '2',
    upVotes: 3,
    downVotes:2,
    noOfAnswers: 0,
    questionTitle:"What Is Function In JS?",
    questionBody:"It Meant To Be",
    questionTags:["javascript", "python"],
    userPosted: "lano",
    userId: 1,
    askedOn:"jan 1",
    answer: [{
      answerBody: "Answer",
      userAnswered: "kumar",
      answerOn: " jan 2",
      userId: 2,
    }] 
  },{
    _id: '3',
    upVotes: 1,
    downVotes:0,
    noOfAnswers: 1,
    questionTitle:"How To Use A Function?",
    questionBody:"By Adding Const",
    questionTags:["javascript", "r", "python", "Css"],
    userPosted: "mano",
    userId: 1,
    askedOn:"jan 2",
    answer: [{
      answerBody: "Answer",
      userAnswered: "kumar",
      answerOn: " jan 2",
      userId:2,
    }]

  }]
```

This is error i am getting
Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

Check the render method of `QuestionsDetails`. See https://reactjs.org/link/warning-keys for more information.
at div
at QuestionsDetails (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:2904:66)
at div
at div
at DisplayQuestions
at Routes (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:42928:5)
at AllRoutes
at Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:42861:15)
at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:41670:5)
at div
at App

Comment: Every element of a list in JSX has to have a key. Object you posted doesn't matter.

Comment: how are you rendering the list, can you add that code too ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73786792/reactjs-render-error-each-child-in-a-list-should-have-a-unique-key-prop This is Th Way I Am Rendering My Code

Comment: You are using `question.id` to use as the key prop while your array does not contain the `id` on a question. use `question._id` instead.

Answer (score -1):

Try once by adding the index as a key.

like

```
questionList.map((question,index) => (
                    <Questions question={question} key={index}/>
               ))
```

Comment: using indexes is a bad practice. `questionList.map(question => <Questions question={question} key={question._id}/>)` should do the trick